# Verifying $\frac{\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x}{1-\tan^2 x} = \cos^2 x$

Tags: trigonometry

> $$\frac{\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x}{1-\tan^2 x} = \cos^2 x$$

Also, we have not learned the massive list of identities.  We were taught to derive everything. I don't know if this necessarily matters, just an FYI.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: The left-hand side is given by $$\frac{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}{1-\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}}=\frac{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}{\frac{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}}=…$$

Comment: When you multiplied by the reciprocal, obviously the next part is that it would cancel out the numerator of the left side.  I am knowingly mistaken, but wouldn't multiplying by the reciprocal engage the reciprocal identities, making this impossible?

Answer (score 2):

$$1-\tan^2{(x)}=1-\frac{\sin^2{(x)}}{\cos^2{(x)}}=\frac1{\cos^2{(x)}}(\cos^2{(x)}-\sin^2{(x)})$$
$$\therefore \frac{\cos^2{(x)}-\sin^2{(x)}}{1-\tan^2{(x)}}=\frac1{\left(\frac1{\cos^2{(x)}}\right)}=\cos^2{(x)}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}{1-\tan^2(x)}=\cos^2(x)$

This means that $\frac{\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}=1-\tan^2(x)$

The left hand side simplfied to $1-\tan^2(x)$, which is the right hand side.